# How to debug Quantum GIS PlugIn Visual Studio DLL?

Tags: qgis

I have developed a Quantum GIS plugin layer using Microsoft Visual studio and placed it in my plugins folder of my customized QGIS application.

I now intend to debug the DLL using Microsoft Studio.

I have Quantum GIS 1.8 sources and debug successfully compile and also try to debug my dll using this environment without success.

My question is: How can i debug a Quantum GIS DLL using Microsoft Studio?

Comment: You might be better off posting this in the QGIS mailing lists.